# WPF Webdings: the output of both 'r' and 'R' is the same

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, wpf-controls

I hope the title pretty much explained my problem. In Webdings the output of 'r' is 'Close button' character, but my application is showing some other icon. To be precise it's showing the icon associated with 'R'. How to rectify the problem?

**Edit Code and Picture**

```
 <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCharacter.Name}" 
                               MaxWidth="100"
                               MaxHeight="200"/>
                    <Button Margin="10, 0, 5, 0"
                            Background="{x:Null}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="Webdings">r</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

But the output is as follows

[image]

Instead of small rectangle there should be a small 'X' icon, but VS is treating both 'r' and 'R' as the same.

Comment: Any example code for us to see what you are doing would be of help.

Comment: I uploaded the code as requested

Comment: Works correctly on my form - both upper & lowercase R give the expected symbol.

Comment: But not on mine. Damn!

Comment: Sorry :-( difficult to help when the problem can't be replicated.

Comment: @tinku92 Do you use something like an Lower-To-Uppercase-Converter? And does it only occure in the preview of Visual Studio or also when you run the application?

Comment: Restarting the visual studio helped. Now it's working fine. Still can't figure out what's the problem though.